# Hashicorp Vault Database Secret Engine - Track dynamic users generated by Vault

Tags: mysql, devops, hashicorp-vault

I have configured Vault Database Secret Engine with MySQL. Vault generates a unique user each time we ask for temporary credentials. Sometimes we want to know which user has executed the query in the database.

Upon finding the user, how shall I map the user name generated by Vault with the one who query the credentials from Vault? For example, if John with a token queries at:

```
database/creds/vault-mysql-role
```

and vault generates the user name for John:

```
v-token-vault-mysq-2OSTesyjNuCk9
```

How shall I match the user `v-token-vault-mysq-2OSTesyjNuCk9` with John and find out that it was John who executed the query! I have checked audit logs but doesn't seem contain any info like this.

Answer (score 1):

The audit log does contain this information, just not directly.

The audit log includes the response sent to the client, but all values are hashed. You can use the [sys/audit-hash endpoint](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/system/audit-hash) to compute the hash for the username you're looking for, and then search the audit log for a record with the `response.data.username` field set to this hash:

```
$ vault write sys/audit-hash/file input=v-token-vault-mysq-2OSTesyjNuCk9
Key     Value
---     -----
hash    hmac-sha256:c78424ed34000ffdde18d51bc950507129a2fece391d12fcd1095336204ed460

$ grep hmac-sha256:c78424ed34000ffdde18d51bc950507129a2fece391d12fcd1095336204ed460 audit.log | jq .
{
  "auth": {
    "token_type": "service",
    "client_token": "hmac-sha256:5a134faa99fd944a8be6d58fff9aa0e2794241ca25972e5cd8b65feb4bec9713",
    "accessor": "NkBx2TO4h10cN2iqKboDweFE",
    "policies": [
      "default",
      "database"
    ],
    "display_name": "token-bd6b709e-99d6-bd29-fedd-fd5c97ef6564-my-app",
    "token_policies": [
      "default",
      "database"
    ]
  },
  "request": {
    "operation": "read",
    "id": "40198a5b-2796-e4f9-51b4-1094db130468",
    "client_token_accessor": "NkBx2TO4h10cN2iqKboDweFE",
    "client_token": "hmac-sha256:5a134faa99fd944a8be6d58fff9aa0e2794241ca25972e5cd8b65feb4bec9713",
    "path": "database/creds/vault-mysql-role",
    "namespace": {
      "id": "root"
    },
    "remote_address": "192.0.2.1"
  },
  "response": {
    "data": {
      "username": "hmac-sha256:f746cf79101e8aa1f5f225af1a5bcc43d34040ccb00739551aa8be6455951a25",
      "password": "hmac-sha256:c78424ed34000ffdde18d51bc950507129a2fece391d12fcd1095336204ed460"
    },
    "secret": {
      "lease_id": "database/creds/my-app/ISAf9HmK4REjTBhVnKbzJ3sw"
    }
  },
  "type": "response"
}
```

I made these values up, of course, but you can see that the `auth` field contains a bunch of information about the client.

If the auth fields are not sufficient, you can use the `auth.accessor` field with the [auth/token/lookup-accessor endpoint](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/auth/token#lookup-a-token-accessor) to get a bit more, such as an entity_id, for example, which can be mapped to a persona (see [Identity: Entities and Groups](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/identity-access-management/iam-identity), [identity/lookup/entity](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/identity/lookup#lookup-an-entity)).